# First attempts with SSS - where is the nose?

Tags: shaders, subsurface-scattering

I am trying to make the skin for my female mesh and watched some tutorials on Skin Shaders. I tried to rebuild YanSculpts Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktsyL2Kp5bQ&t=388s and the result looked like his ... on the sphere.

When I append the material to my mesh file and use it, it looks way more glossy strangely. Maybe the lighting? or what could it be?
What bugs me more though is that everything is so washed out. I cannot even make out the nose anymore ... why is that? Do I need to manually add some kind of Ambient Occlusion?

This is the tutorial result for me, which I like:

[image: This is the tutorial result for me, which I like]

This is my mesh with the skin texture minus the bump - why can I not make out the features at all - I even like the solid shaded version better than this. I took out some lights. With stronger lights the nose is even less visible ...

[image: This is my mesh with the skin texture minus the bump - why can I not make out the features at all - I even like the solid shaded version better than this]

These are the nodes, but they should be the same in both, except that the female mesh has no bump yet and a slightly different color
[image]

This is the mesh with just a plain diffuse shader and no sss, no glossy, besides it not looking like skin, at least I can make out the facial features.

[image]

Comment: The SSS BSDF ist highly scale dependant. Try changing the scale value to compensate the size difference of your two models.

Comment: @Leander Ok, will do. The hair and breasts are dynamic too though. So they might behave differently then as well, right? So maybe changing the values of the nodes is better than the scale of the female mesh (which is around 2 blender units tall). The sphere is the standard size (1 blender unit?).

Comment: Yes change the scales of the material setup.